# react native: animation not triggering in release mode

Tags: animation, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying my react native app on android and iOS using the release mode. unfortunately, there is an animation that doesn't trigger in release mode which works perfectly on debug mode.

i have tried to use the 'useNativeDriver: true' which improved the animation on android but didn't fix the issue

for ref: 
"react-native": "0.56.0"

my Drawer.js

```
toggle = () => {
    Animated.timing(this.x_translate, {
        toValue: this.state.drawerOpen ? 0 : 1,
        duration: this.state.animationDuration,
        useNativeDriver: true
    }).start();
    this.setState({ drawerOpen: !this.state.drawerOpen })
}


render() {
    const menu_moveX = this.x_translate.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [-this.state.width, 0]
    });

    return (
        <Animated.View style={[this.props.style, styles.drawer, {
            transform: [
                {
                    translateX: menu_moveX
                }
            ]
        }]}>
            <ImageBackground
                source={require('../images/background.png')}
                style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', alignItems: 'center' }}
            >
                <View style={styles.blank}></View>
                <AutoHeightImage source={require('../images/image.png')} width={0.7 * this.state.width} />
                <LineDashboard navigate={this.props.navigate} items={[this.menu[0], this.menu[1]]} sizeIcon={30} />
                <LineDashboard navigate={this.props.navigate} items={[this.menu[2], this.menu[3]]} sizeIcon={30} />
                <LineDashboard navigate={this.props.navigate} items={[this.menu[4], this.menu[5]]} sizeIcon={30} />
            </ImageBackground>

        </Animated.View>
    )
}
```

my dashboard.js

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
        handleThis: () => {
            console.log(this.drawer);
            this.setState({ loaded: true })
            this.drawer.toggle();
        }
    });
}

static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params = {} } = navigation.state;
    return {
        headerTitle: 'Home Page',
        headerLeft: (
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                    params.handleThis();
                }}
                style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}
            >
                <Icon name="menu" size={25} color="black" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
        headerRight: (
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                    console.log(navigation);
                    // navigation.goBack(null)
                    navigation.navigate('Login');
                }}
                style={{ marginRight: 20 }}
            >
                <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>Log Out</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

        )
    }
}


render() {

    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    return (
        <View style={styles.page}>
            <ScrollView>
                <View style={styles.pageContainer}>



                    <View style={{ height: 30 }} />

                    <AutoHeightImage source={require('../images/patient_primary_logo_white.png')} width={0.7 * width} />
                    <View style={styles.separator} />

                    <DashboardNotificationTile title={'Your Notifications'} onPress={() => navigate('Notifications')}>
                        <Text>You have 2 new notifications</Text>
                        <Text>Please click to see more</Text>
                    </DashboardNotificationTile>

                    <DashboardTile title={'Your Visits'}>
                        <Text>You have 1 upcoming visit</Text>
                        <SimpleButton onPress={() => navigate('ToBook')} title='View All Visits' width={'100%'} style={{ marginTop: 16 }} color={'green'}/>
                    </DashboardTile>

                    <DashboardTile title={'Your Expense Claims'}>
                        <Text>You have 2 open expense claims</Text>
                        <SimpleButton onPress={() => navigate('Open')} title='View All Expense Claims' width={'100%'} style={{ marginTop: 16 }} />
                    </DashboardTile>

                </View>
            </ScrollView>

            <DrawerDashboard navigate={navigate} onRef={(ref) => this.drawer = ref} style={this.state.loaded ? { opacity: 1 } : { opacity: 0 }} />

        </View >

    )
}
```

in Dashboard.js, i have a headerLeft that should trigger the function handleThis() which doesn't seems to be doing. however, when pressed, the TouchableOpacity component stay 'selected' rather than coming back to its original state.

any suggestion?
thanks

**EDIT:**

the issue occurs at any time when the debugger is not on. sorry i just discovered it right now. The animation works perfectly if the remote JS debugger is launched.

So, i thought the issue may be the processing time, as the app is working slower when the debugger is on, maybe my handleThis() function was not loaded...
So, I moved the setParams() from the ComponentDidMount to WillMount.

didn't worked :\

Any suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean by "release mode"? How did you install your app?

Comment: @Kraylog what i mean by "release mode" is that the react native server is running inside the app rather than on my computer. On iOS I just changed the build configuration scheme from Debug to release. On Android I created a release key with password and build a signed APK. Hope that helps clarify

Comment: When you're using a release on a phone, there is no "react native server". The code is bundled with the app, and not configured to get it from the bundler. For this reason I'm not sure you're testing what you think you are.

Comment: @Kraylog sorry for the bad wording, i checked the doc, you are right. However, I think i have done it properly as i have already released react native apps on the stores and followed what I previously explained. 
Anyway, as I also mentioned in the EDIT of my post, the issue always happens when the debugger is off (code bundled within the app or not)

Comment: @Panda-Toine I am experiencing the same. Have you found out the solution so far?